# how to disable phone keyboard while app is running?

Tags: android, calculator, android-softkeyboard, delphi-xe5

hello i am making an app calculator for android when the user click's on the edit-box the keyboard pops (Phone) up how can i disable keyboard when app is running??
Reason is I have already made the number button's so the keyboard make it really hard to navigate.

Thank you

Comment: Mention that you are programing in Delphi xe5...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to disable the soft keyboard, add attribute in xml of that edit text.

```
<EditText android:id=".."
      ..
      android:focusable="false" />
```

It will stop the execution of soft keyboard.

or

Create your own class that extends EditText and override the onCheckIsTextEditor():

```
public class NoImeEditText extends EditText {
public EditTextEx(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) { 
super(context, attrs);     
}      
@Override      
public boolean onCheckIsTextEditor() {   
return false;     
}        
}
```